# alter table then update in single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, etl, talend

I have a requirement where I need to Alter (Add 2 columns) and then update the same table.

Here is the query I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD c1 int,c2 varchar(10)

UPDATE  A set c1 = 23, c2 = 'ZZXX'
```

I need to run the above two queries at a time.

I am using Talend ETL tool, in this we have a component tMssqlrow, which allow us to run multiple queries (I am using 10 to 15 update queries in single component).

But the above query is not working.

I tested in DataBase Microsoft SQL. i am getting the below error :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
> Invalid column name 'c1'. Msg 207,
>
> Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
> Invalid column name 'c2'.

can any one help me resolve this problem.

Comment: add `GO` after the `ALTER` statement.

Comment: if we use go in MSSQL it is working but i can not use go in talend, talend is throghing error :: syntax error near go

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't do this *exactly* in a single statement (or batch) and it seems the tool you are using does not support `GO` as a batch delimiter.

You can use `EXEC` to run it in a child batch though.

```
ALTER TABLE A
  ADD c1 INT, c2 VARCHAR(10);

EXEC('
UPDATE A
SET    c1 = 23,
       c2 = ''ZZXX'';
    ');
```

NB: All single quotes in the query need to be doubled up as above to escape them inside a string literal.

Or alternatively you could achieve similar results in a single statement with the aid of some default constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE A
  ADD c1 INT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_A_c1 DEFAULT 23 WITH VALUES, 
     c2 VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT DF_A_c2 NULL DEFAULT 'ZZXX' WITH VALUES;
```

But this is not exactly the same as the original query as the default constraints will be left behind and may need to be dropped.

Answer (score 4):

Use GO between your 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD c1 int,c2 varchar(10)

GO

UPDATE  A set c1 = 23, c2 = 'ZZXX'

GO
```