# Alter then update causes an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
               WHERE table_name = 'T1' AND column_name = 'C1')
BEGIN
    ALTER Table T1
        ADD C1 BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T1_C1 DEFAULT 0   

   UPDATE Table T1 
   SET C1 = 1
END
GO
```

I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

I tried [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741378/3664659) but it didn't update column value. I came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443262/add-column-to-table-and-then-update-it-inside-transaction) but I think this is not my case as I don't want to catch exceptions or do any transaction. Do I have easy option to do this?

Putting GO seperator didn't help too.

As Joe Taras pointed out, I have changed my script but now getting error

> Invalid column name 'C1'.

Comment: New error is because first the batch is *compiled* and then it's executed. At the point where it's trying to *compile* the `UPDATE` statement, no such column exists.

Comment: can you not just change the default value as I have posted in my solution? then you don't even require the update?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that that `UPDATE` isn't *compiled* until after you're actually created the column.

Put it in a separate context by using `EXEC`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
               WHERE table_name = 'T1' AND column_name = 'C1')
BEGIN
    ALTER Table T1
        ADD C1 BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T1_C1 DEFAULT 0   

   EXEC('UPDATE Table T1 
         SET C1 = 1')
END
GO
```

Comment: +1 `You need to ensure that that UPDATE isn't compiled until after you're actually created the column`.  Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Your row:

```
UPDATE Table T1 SET C1 = 1
```

has wrong because you have specified table keyword.

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE T1 SET C1 = 1
```

**EDIT 1**

Rewrite your script as follow, so after GO separator you'll update your field, so you are sure the DDL has taken by DBMS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
               where table_name = 'T1' AND column_name = 'C1')
BEGIN
    ALTER Table T1
    ADD C1 BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T1_C1 DEFAULT 0    
END
GO

UPDATE T1 SET C1 = 1
```

**EDIT 2**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
               where table_name = 'T1' AND column_name = 'C1')
BEGIN
    ALTER Table T1
    ADD C1 BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T1_C1 DEFAULT 0  

    EXEC('UPDATE T1 SET C1 = 1')  
END
GO
```

Comment: Only 'ALTER' needs the 'Table' keyword.

Comment: I can't write update out side if, because if script is run again, it will update C1. It should be run only when column is created.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no entry in the table update cannot be done 
try it after giving asingle entry it works