# "Invalid column name" with Entity Framework migrations

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having an issue with updating a database with a migration that adds a column to a table and assign values to it. I have reduced the issue to a very simple case.

Here's the model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is the context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

First, I enabled migrations, created an initial migration and create a database.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration -Name Initial
PM> Update-Database
```

Then, I extended my model:

```
public int Col3 { get; set; }
```

and created a new migration:

```
PM> Add-Migration -Name AddedCol3
```

I modified that migration to update the values in Col3, see the call to Sql():

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Models", "Col3", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    Sql("update dbo.Models set Col3 = Col2");
}

public override void Down()
{
   DropColumn("dbo.Models", "Col3");
}
```

When I update the database with this migration, I get:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'Col3'.

The generated script is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] ADD [Col3] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
update dbo.Models set Col3 = Col2
-- Removed update to migration history.
```

Apparently, SQL Server cannot handle the alter table and update in one batch.

I tried to add `SQL("GO");` in between, but this results in the error:

> The argument 'sql' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.

when trying to update.

How can I use migrations to achieve this. I want my Up() and Down() methods to consistently update the database.

Comment: You are correct, they have to be different batches. You can use `execute` [**like this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741378/6167855) as one work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-around provided by @scsimon translates to the SQL-statement

```
Sql("EXEC('update dbo.Models set Col3 = Col2')");
```

and script

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] ADD [Col3] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
EXEC('update dbo.Models set Col3 = Col2')
```

and works fine.

I prefer this method, as I expect it to be less fulnerable to EF modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around by adding a dummy SQL-statement:

```
Sql("select 1\nGO");
```

The resulting script is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] ADD [Col3] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO

select 1

update dbo.Models set Col3 = Col2
```

Note that the `GO` statement has automagically been moved to another location!

Anyway, the script is now accepted by SQL Server and the changes are applied the way they are itended.